# Set Permissions on Folder without Processing Sub Files and Folders

Tags: powershell, ntfs, propagation

I have two related issues that I am trying to solve. I want to update an ACL on a folder without it processing all of the children. My first example is when setting "This folder only" on a high level file, setting the permissions takes forever because it processes all of the children. The second example is that I have a file system were Everyone is directly applied to each item and I need to remove the entry without taking the time to process the children. I have used Get/Set-ACL and Get/Remove/Add-NTFSAccess, but cannot figure out how to stop the processing of the children objects.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS inheritance is similar to genetic inheritance. As we, as children, get to blame our parents for all our faults whether they like it or not, child objects decide whether they inherit permissions from parent objects.

You cannot, using NTFS, change a permission on a parent object and tell it not to allow propagation to child objects.